# How to check a string for a question mark?

Tags: c#

I want to check if an inputted string contains a question mark. 
Probably quite simple but I'm new to coding.

Comment: `String.Contains` is your friend.

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn about where to find documentation. Start at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api and search for string - then look through https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7#Methods for useful methods

Comment: I would also suggest learning some regex because `contains`, `startswith` and `endswith` will take you far but when you need to do more advanced things regex really helps. I really suggest https://regex101.com/ for learning regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`String.Contains()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) :

```
string myString = "Hello world?";
bool containsQuestionMark = myString.Contains("?"); // true
```

For future references, use [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/index), it's filled with good documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively (to Rick's answer), if you are checking just for char occurance in a string you can use IndexOf(char):

```
bool containsQuestionMark = myString.IndexOf('?') != -1;
```

There are also some minor (negligible) performance differences between two approaches, depending on the framework version being used.